# Multiple jquery document.ready on a page trough ajax

Tags: jquery

I have a page which uses jQuery `document.ready`, to populate the content of a div when a button is clicked.

The content inside the div also uses jquery to create some hover preview of an image (also inside this div). But I can not use `document.ready` again. How should this be implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `document.ready` as many times as you like. They're executed top-to-bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Use callbacks or functions. Or both.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(element).click(function(){
        alert('bla')
    });
    $(element).hover(function(){
        call_alert('bla');
    });
});
function call_alert(stringer) { alert(stringer) }
```

Comment: So if you but in tjat button atribute: onClick="call_alert('hello there')" it will work as you want.

Comment: One of the main reasons for using jquery is so we don't need to have our js functionality in the html markup

Comment: I dont think thats bad. And resetings events after AJAX is is hard thought.

Answer (score 0):

if you do the following, it is similar to document.ready

```
(function(){
    //your code here
    alert('this fired when the dom was ready');
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Really though the question isn't actually related to document.ready. That just makes it so the script isn't executed until everything in the dom is loaded into browser cache. Basically just create your function to bind the button click to then on its call back bind the hover function to the image. Otherwise look into the .live() function for the images.

Comment: This could be a great answer. If you aren't actually in need of document.ready, you should use .live... http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready(function() {
})

Simply says execute the code within this anonymous function on the ready event of the document object, an event which fires when the dom is loaded.

Within that you can have as many functions assigned to as many events as you wish.

Javascript is parsed before the dom is loaded, and all the functions are bound to the events in the browser's memmory. So, what you are saying is bind all these functions to all these events but only after the dom is ready, which saves it looking for elements that haven't been parsed yet.

You can do it like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("h1").click(function() {
alert("Someone clicked h1");
});
$("h2").hover(function() {
alert("someone is hovering our h2s"); //never do this as it will fire endless alerts and crash the browser.
})
})
```

Or like this:

```
function hover_func(el) {
alert("someone is hovering over"+el.tagName);
}

function hover_func(el) {
alert("someone clicked"+el.tagName);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
$("h1").click('click_func($(this))');
$("h2").hover('hover_func($(this))');
})
```